# mysql query error

Tags: mysql

```
select a.pdt_id, a.end_date - now() as seconds, 
  b.bid_price, c.uname, c.profile_img 
from tbl_products a 
  left join tbl_auction b on a.pdt_id=b.product_id 
  left join tbl_members c on  b.member_id=c.member_id 
where a.pdt_id=183
```

I have called this query in SetTimeOut() method of javascript, for every 1 second 
it displays the result as

```
pdt_id    seconds       price    uname          profile_img            
183      107959.000000  0.10    xxxxxxx     images/profile/no_image.jpg
```

everything is correct, what is my problem is when seconds become 183 it doesn't display the seconds the output will be:

```
pdt_id   price    uname          profile_img            
183      0.10   xxxxxxx     images/profile/no_image.jpg
```

What is the error in that query()?  If necessary I will give the table details...

Comment: Where are you calling this query from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select ..., subdate(a.end_date, now()) as seconds,
```

Comment: if a.end_date is null, you'll get a null. try `if_null(a.end_date, now()) - now()` instead

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do math on dates like this

```
a.end_date - now() as seconds
```

That's your bug.

here's an alternative

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e.end_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP() as seconds
```

unix_timestamp represents the date as an integer of the number of seconds since 1970 which is a bonafide number and it works.

the reason your method sometimes works is because NOW() - end_date sometimes is good math but dates' aren't base 10 numbers so eventually you get a screwy result when you treat them as such.

Comment: i have tried this too unix_timestamp(a.end_date) - unix_timestamp('".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."') but still there is a problem

Comment: unix_timestamp(a.end_date) - unix_timestamp()   your date business is not required.... the default is NOW. or if you want to be more explicit.  unix_timestamp(NOW())

Comment: hi, i found that the error is in some other part of the php code